# How to browserify javascript as a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, cross-browser, browserify

I want to browserify my javascript before sending it to the browser. Is it possible to pass a javascript as a string in browserify? For example:

```
browserify("let a =1; console.log(a)");
```

I have done by passing a JS file path like:

```
const browserified = await browserify(browserJSFilePath);
```

but I want the flexibility to also pass the javascript as a string. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to pass a string, but you can use a stream. And you can create a stream out of the string with a package called [string-to-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-to-stream). Then you can simply use it like this:

```js
var browserify = require('browserify');
const str = require('string-to-stream');
var b = browserify();
b.add(str("let a =1; console.log(a)"));
b.bundle((err, buffer)=>{
  console.log(buffer.toString());
})
```